# How to extract ZIP files on SD card via MTP from Linux?

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, linux, mtp, zip

I need to copy 200,000 files from my computer running Debian to the SD card on my Moto E running Lollipop.

I have installed mtp-tools and can mount the SD card in Thunar via MTP. I attempted to copy the 200,000 files directly, but Thunar estimated this would take 200 hours to complete. So I compressed the files inside some ZIP files, which only took a few minutes to copy to the SD card.

Now that the ZIP is copied over, is there any way I can use Linux utilities to extract the files found on the SD card, without installing a file manager on the phone?

Comment: This solution worked for me. I installed busybox to get the unzip command.

Comment: I'm going to write it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

In order to unpack a ZIP file that's located on your phone, you can make use of the **unzip** command, which is included in BusyBox. To execute it, you can either install a Terminal emulator on the phone, or use **adb** from a computer with your phone plugged to it via USB.

---

### ADB method

Before plugging your phone to the computer, make sure that the checkbox near **USB debugging**, located in the **Developer settings**, has been selected.

Next, plug your phone to the computer, start a shell on the latter and install **ADB**, which you'll use as a means to execute commands in your phone.

After the installation is complete, start ADB by issuing `adb shell`, which will trigger an authorization dialog on your phone's screen. Accept it, and focus on the newly issued command, since you might have noticed that a new, differently prefixed shell has taken your previous one's place on the computer: you're now commanding your phone.

Now, from the ADB shell, `cd` to the directory where your ZIP is located, and create a new directory with `mkdir Directory` (replace `Directory` with a name of your choice).

Finally, issue `unzip archive.zip -d Directory`, replacing `archive.zip` with your archive's name; the contents of the archive will then be extracted to the specified `Directory`.

Should you find too much output cluttering your shell, replace the unzip command above with `unzip archive.zip -d Directory &> /dev/null`, which will silence the command.